# php form sending me blank mails

Tags: php, forms, email

My form keeps sending me blank mails every once in a while from my host (`www@servage-customer.net`)

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$email_id="email@example.com";
$userName=$_REQUEST['userName'];
$userEmail=$_REQUEST['userEmail'];
$userPhone=$_REQUEST['userPhone'];
$userMsg=$_REQUEST['userMsg'];
$subject = "Bericht van ".$userName; 
$message = '<html><head><title>'.$subject.'</title></head><body><table><tr><td>Email :  </td><td> '.$userEmail.'</td></tr><td><tr>Telefoonnummer</tr></td><td><tr> '.$userPhone.'</tr></td>
<tr><td>Naam : </td><td> '.$userName.'</td></tr><tr><td>Bericht : </td><td> '.$userMsg.'</td>
</tr></table></body></html>';
//$message = "Email:  ".$userEmail. "\r\nNaam: ".$userName."\r\nBericht : ".$userMsg;
$to=$email_id;
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($userEmail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($userEmail) . "\r\n";
//$headers .= "CC: email@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
      $mail_status='no';
      header("Location: index.html");
      exit();
}else{
      $mail_status='yes';
      header("Location: contact.html");
      exit();

} ?>
```

I really don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: May I ask why you don't use phpmailer?

Comment: Instead of phpmailer I'd recommend SwiftMailer

    Send emails using SMTP, sendmail, postfix or a custom Transport implementation of your own
    Support servers that require username & password and/or encryption
    Protect from header injection attacks without stripping request data content
    Send MIME compliant HTML/multipart emails
    Use event-driven plugins to customize the library
    Handle large attachments and inline/embedded images with low memory use

Comment: If you're being sent blank email on occasion is is A. because someone/something is running the script and 2.) you're not checking to see if any of the variables are set before you allow the script to send an e-amil.

Comment: What do you mean with blank mails? Do you mean even the subject? It does send it to the right email? Does it still redirect you to the same page?

Comment: You have no input handling that checks if fields are empty or not, so every time someone calls that php page will just send you an empty mail...

Comment: your code looks good. Try adding stripslashes function for `$subject` , `$userMsg` , `$userName` then run this script again.

Comment: @walkingRed I never heard of it..

Comment: what you need to do is use conditional statements and other functions made for stuff like this; that's why you're getting blank emails. sessions and tokens is another

Comment: @Demerkies ok :) Now you have perfect opportunity to start using it. First check project page of [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and if you encounter some problems check tag `phpmailer` on StackOverflow.

Comment: try to write your message variable in one line or concatenate it with . dot if you wants to use it in multiple lines.

Comment: @Loko it sends it to the right email. the sender is my host, it's not that i sended them myself

Comment: @JayBlanchard you can't just send emails because then it will tell you to fill in the forms

Comment: Apparently not @Demerkies, you *are* getting occasional blank emails.

Comment: this is an explosion of information, I thank you all but I'm just a student  software developer in my second year. this is the website I am using it on: [link](http://kapsalon-ariana.nl/contact.html)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sounds like a case of a missing shoe to me *Sam.*

Comment: I agree *Ralph* and it may also point to the missing sock @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Naruto you are right! everytime i call the .php file i recieve an email, but it also sends randomly how is that possible? and how can i fix this?

Comment: By checking if a button was pressed and/or details were filled in..

Comment: @Naruto none of that happened, all I do is open the page and it sends me a blank mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works fine, the problem is probably you visit the .php file directly, which send a blank mail.